# Compilation error in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

**[dcc32 Error] MSSQLQuery.pas(29): E2037 Declaration of 'DataEvent' differs from previous declaration**

I have done some research and found that this issue is caused during function overriding, if the declaration in super class and sub class are different

DataEvent is a library function and Ive checked the library and found that the declaration in code is correct ,but Im not sure why this compilation error occurs

I have also confirmed that there is only one DataEvent function in this class

I am new to Delphi So please help me in resolving this error

This is the class I have defined

```
 TMSSQLQuery = Class (TADOQuery)
    Private
      FAutoNoLock : Boolean;
    Protected
      procedure DataEvent(Event: TDataEvent; Info: Longint); override;
    Public
      Constructor Create (AOwner : TComponent);Override;
      Destructor  Destroy;Override;
  End;
```

This is the procedure definition

```
Procedure  TMSSQLQuery.DataEvent(Event: TDataEvent; Info: Longint);
Begin
  { Call inherited method }
  Inherited DataEvent (Event, Info);
  If Event in [deConnectChange, dePropertyChange]
    Then RefreshParams;
End;
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure MSSQLQuery.pas or a related file is not changed? 2) Are you sure there is no other MSSQLQuery 3) Have you tried to close the delphi IDE and restart? (it often gets instable). 4) Can you post the code of the declaration of DataEvent and its ancestor.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual code line (line 29) that's causing the compiler error.

Comment: I have added the code in the question

Comment: I've already explained why this is happening. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: After your recent edit, the issue is clear.

You've declared your DataEvent handler with a second parameter of `LongInt`:

```
procedure DataEvent(Event: TDataEvent; Info: Longint); override;
```

The VCL defines it as `NativeInt` (see the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADODataSet.DataEvent)):

```
procedure DataEvent(Event: TDataEvent; Info: NativeInt); override;
```

`NativeInt` and `LongInt` are not the same in that declaration, and therefore the descendant class definition does not match that of the ancestor you're attempting to override. (See the next section of my answer).

This error occurs if you have a declaration in the implementation section that is different from the interface declaration.

```
type
  TSomeClass=class(TSomething)
    procedure DoThisThing(const AParameter: TSomeParamType);
  end;

implementation

// Note difference in parameter name
procedure TSomeClass.DoThisThing(AParam: TSomeParamType);
begin

end;

// This would cause the same error - note the missing 'const'
procedure TSomeClass.DoThisThing(AParameter: TSomeParamType);
begin

end;

// This can cause the same error - note different param type
procedure TSomeClass.DoThisThing(AParameter: TDiffParamType);
```

The easiest solution to the problem is to use Class Completion to write the implementation definition for you. Type the declaration in the `interface`, and then (while still in that class definition) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It will generate the proper method stub in the implementation section for you.

(You can generate several at the same time; just declare them all before using the keystroke combination. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> (or <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) helps you move back and forth between the implementation and interface sections.)

The documentation (see below) indicates that this error message also occurs when you try to override a virtual method, but the overriding method has a different parameter list, calling convention etc. This code is from that linked documentation:

```
type
  MyClass = class
    procedure Proc(Inx: Integer);
    function Func: Integer;
    procedure Load(const Name: string);
    procedure Perform(Flag: Boolean);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy(Msg: string); override;      (*<-- Error message here*)
    class function NewInstance: MyClass; override;  (*<-- Error message here*)
  end;
```

For more info, see the Delphi documentation for [E2037](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/E2037_Declaration_of_%27%25s%27_differs_from_previous_declaration_%28Delphi%29).